# How to load fragments dynamically in one activity in android?

Tags: android

I would like to dynamically load fragments in one activity.
Please give me any direction.

Comment: who prevents you to load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FooFragment f = new FooFragment();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, f)
                .commit();
```

You need to use fragment manager in order to load fragments, I suppose you already use support library.